# strange unalignment between plot of waves and other graphical elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

I tried to make a picture of some waves with arrows on top.
I am surprised to see that the arrows don't really appear on top,
but rather slightly below. 
I don't even know why this happens. 
The explicitly forces the arrows to start on top of the waves.
How can I solve this?
[image]

I hope I can readjust the arrows in an elegant way, in the `\newcommand` statements. Thanks in advance for you help.

```
\documentclass{article}

% First command that computes the hight of a single wave on position x.
\newcommand{\wave}[3]{
    #2*#2 / (cosh(#2*(#1 - #3) + ln(#2))*cosh(#2*(#1 - #3) + ln(#2)))
}

% Command to draw a single wave, with its arrow (supposed to be on top),
\newcommand{\drawwave}[2]{
    \fill [samples = 200, color=blue, domain={#1 - 7/#2}:{#1 + 7/#2}]
        plot(\x, \wave{\x}{#2}{#1});
    \draw[->, color=green](#1,{\wave{#1}{#2}{#1}}) -- (#1 + 5*#2,{\wave{#1}{#2}{#1}});
}

%the four necessary packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
    \selectlanguage{dutch}

\begin{document}

    % Drawing four waves.
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.2]
        \draw [color = blue](0,0) -- (60,0);
        \drawwave{10}{0.5};
        \drawwave{25}{1.5};
        \drawwave{45}{1};
        \drawwave{35}{2}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It might be interesting to note that only when the second parameter is equal to `2`, the arrow really starts on top of the wave.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow I am sorry, I edited the same time as you. I hope I didn't delete your edits.

Comment: oh you did, but I "restored" them ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `{\wave{\x}{#2}{#1}}` expands differently from `\wave{\x}{#2}{#1}`.  Second, as can be seen from the corrected plot, the peak value does not occur at `\x=#1`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% First command that computes the hight of a single wave on position x.
\newcommand{\wave}[3]{
    #2*#2 / (cosh(#2*(#1 - #3) + ln(#2))*cosh(#2*(#1 - #3) + ln(#2)))
}

% Command to draw a single wave, with its arrow (supposed to be on top),
\newcommand{\drawwave}[2]{
    \fill [samples = 200, color=blue, domain={#1 - 4/#2}:{#1 + 4/#2}]
        plot(\x, {\wave{\x}{#2}{#1}});
    \draw[->, color=green] (#1,{\wave{#1}{#2}{#1}}) -- (#1 + 5*#2,{\wave{#1}{#2}{#1}});
}

%the four necessary packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    % Drawing four waves.
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.2]
        \draw [color = blue](0,0) -- (60,0);
        \drawwave{10}{0.5};
        \drawwave{25}{1.5};
        \drawwave{45}{1};
        \drawwave{35}{2}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you. I found out the top was on #1-#1-ln(#2)/#2 and filling that in the code you provided me I got the right result. I still wonder what I did wrong though, and what you actually did. Could you advise me some documentation to understand the use of pgfparsemath?

Comment: There is always the pgf manual.  Mostly this has to do with the tikz parser (which differs from the LaTeX parser).  As a rule, any macros should be surrounded by braces.